# using recursion to calculate total digits

Tags: c, recursion, counting, function-definition

I wrote this code that counts how many 1's there are in an integer using recursion. N has to be less than 9 digits. I can't seem to find what's wrong with my code and why it won't work. If anyone can give me a hint of where I went wrong I'd appreciate it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

int count_ones(int n);

int main()
{
    assert(count_ones(1001)==2);
}

int count_ones(int n)
{   
    int sum = 0;
    int x;
    if(n == 0)
    {
        return sum;
    }
    else if(n > 999999999)
    {
        return sum;
    }
    else if(n <= 999999999)
    {
        x == n%10;
        if (x == 1)
        {
        sum = sum + 1;
        count_ones(n/10);
        }
        else
        {
        count_ones(n/10);  
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Please use your debugger. Problem is that you are not adding result of recursive call.

Comment: what's `x == n % 10;` for?

Answer (score 4):

You're not combining the current `sum` with the result from the recursive call. So you're just counting the last digit, all the other counts are being discarded.

```
int count_ones(int n) {
    if (n == 0 || n > 999999999) {
        return 0;
    } else if (n % 10 == 1) {
        return 1 + count_ones(n / 10);
    } else {
        return count_ones(n / 10);
    }
}
```

Comment: To further optimize, the check `n > 999999999` can be moved out of the function so it is not executed for each recursive call, as it is only needed once

Answer (score 0):

Way too complicated.

Here's how to do it right:

```
int count_ones(int n)
{
    return n? (n%10 == 1) + count_ones(n/10) : 0;
}
```

For completeness, here's an iterative (non-recursive) solution.

```
int count_ones(int n)
{
    int total=0;
    for(;n; n/=10, total += (n%10==1));
    return total;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Barmar's answer is giving you the idea of how to fix your approach. Here is an alternative one, which make the advantage of *tail recursion* which can be unrolled into a loop by the compiler. This approach is using accumulator (`acc`) to count the ones, and will only return it once.

```
int count_ones_rec(int n, int acc)
{
    if (n == 0)
        return acc;
    return count_ones_rec(n / 10, acc + (n % 10 == 1));
}
```

This can be wrapped in a function like:

```
int count_ones(int n)
{
    /* additional checks on `n` if needed */
    return count_ones_rec(n, 0);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For starters there is a typo

```
x == n%10;
```

You mean assignment instead of the comparison

```
x = n%10;
```

In these calls of the function

```
    if (x == 1)
    {
    sum = sum + 1;
    count_ones(n/10);
    }
    else
    {
    count_ones(n/10);  
    }
```

you are not using the returned values of the recursive calls

```
count_ones(n/10);
```

Moreover as the function parameter has the signed type `int` then the user can pass to the function a negative number. In this case the function will return a wrong result.

Pay attention to that such restriction

```
else if(n > 999999999)
```

does not make a sense. The user can enter any number of the acceptable range of values for objects of the type `int`.

The function can look the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

size_t count_ones( int n )
{
    const int Base = 10;
    
    return n == 0 ? 0 : ( n % Base == ( n < 0 ? -1 : 1 ) ) + count_ones( n / Base ); 
}

int main(void) 
{
    printf( "%zu\n", count_ones( -11 ) );
    printf( "%zu\n", count_ones( 11 ) );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
2
2
```

Comment: The function ends with `return sum;` so there's no undefined behavior.